# What is the regular expression for username shouldn't be root

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

What I tried

```
^((?!root).)*$
```

Results

- `root` invalid username
- `admin` valid username
- `rootwee` invalid username (this should be valid)
- `root123` invalid username  (this should be valid)

I tried removing `.` from `regex`, then its not working

Can you please help with this?

Comment: Why regex? Why not just `username === "root"`?

Comment: we can but i am using  ng-pattern in angular js so the submit button enabling and error message can handle easily

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex features a tempered greedy token that disallows a certain substring in the whole input. Thus, "rootwee" and "root123" are invalid.

You can use

```
/^(?!root$)/
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fX4rM3/3)

The anchored lookahead `(?!root$)` makes sure the whole input is not equal to `root`, but the string itself can contain `root`.

Note that when using a literal regex declaration, we needn't match the whole input string.

Here is a demo snippet:

```js
function formCtrl($scope){
  $scope.onSubmit = function(){
    alert("form submitted");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="formCtrl">
  <form name="myForm" ng-submit="onSubmit()">
    <input type="text" name="field" ng-model="formCtrl" ng-pattern="/^(?!root$)/" required>
    <span ng-show="myForm.field.$error.pattern">Not valid!</span>
    <span ng-show="myForm.field.$error.required">This field is required!</span>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, if `^(?!root$)` is enough to "not match" that word and nothing else, what is the extra `.$` for at the end?

Comment: @RavindharKonka Yes, it works, which is why I'm asking the question.  I'm not saying this is wrong (I upvoted it).  I was just wondering as I'm trying to learn regular expressions after avoiding them all my life.

Comment: @Archer: It works with `ng-pattern="/^(?!root$)/"`, but fails with `ng-pattern="^(?!root$)"`. The reason is that when *ng-pattern* evaluates to a string, the whole pattern is enclosed with `^` and `$`. See [*ng-pattern* reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input).

Comment: Yes, I know that.  I expected you'd understand that I simply didn't include the forward slashes.  I just wanted to know why you had chosen to add `.*$` at the end, after already using the `$` to denote the end of the string.

Comment: @Archer: I needed to double check that. Thank you for pointing out that here.

Comment: Thanks for that - I was just confused and thought I still wasn't getting regular expressions at all.  I guess I'm on my way now :D

Comment: @Archer To relieve any confusion, I should confess I confused anglular `ng-pattern` and HTML5 `pattern` attributes. In HTML5, the whole input should be matched with the regex where you cannot use a regex literal.